# How to condition (post-process) resolved array with graphql apollo-server

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to understand how to filter the results of the below graphQL query after the array of assignments has completely resolved.

Specifically there is a nullable subfield and I would like to remove results from for which this nullable subfield is in-fact null.

`type Query { 
  assignments_by_teacher_id(teacher_id: ID!): [Assignment]
}`

`type Assignment implements Viewable {
  view_type                 : ViewType!
  content                   : Content # nullable
  # other fields..
}`

I traced the execution path and see that as expected the resolution follows a breadth first traversal with the nested fields resolving after the root object.  What I'm looking for is a post resolver hook that can condition the resulting array of Assignments based on the fully resolved query response and possibly some argument to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for [prisma/graphql-middleware](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-middleware)

> Allows complete control over your resolvers (Before, After).